# Weird Django URL behavior

Tags: django, django-urls

I have the following URL confs:

`urls.py`:

```
# ...
url(r'^test$', 'project.main.views.test', name='test'),
url(r'^app', include('project.app.urls')),
```

`app/urls.py`:

```
# ...
url(r'^$', 'project.app.views.home', name='home'),
```

When navigating to `example.com/test` I get the proper view. But when naivgating to `example.com/app` I get a 404. `APPEND_SLASH` is set to `TRUE`, if it matters.

Fixing all my URLs to end with a slash solves this, but I rather not have my URLs with those useless slashes at the end.

What am I missing?

Comment: Also discussed on http://groups.google.com/group/pyweb-il/browse_thread/thread/a113dccb12bcbb06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there's some corrupt module in my `PYTHONPATH` which somehow messes up the entire url conf.

When working from a clean environment (i.e. using `virtualenv`), everything works great.